# Where do perls dbi:Oracle table_info/column_info get their information from?

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I've got an (at least i thought so) simple task: Comparing 2 tables by columnnames, datatypes and length only to verify they have the same structure so far. It should be done in an existing perl script which is connecting to two different databases.

First I simply queried each databases `user_tab_columns` and compared the result. Now I found out the hard way that `user_tab_columns` is not live but has to be refreshed by analyzing the table ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277 ), which I absoultly had no idea of.

`describe` gets the actual table definition, but doesn't seem to work through perls dbi:Oracle, so I stumbled upon the `table_info()`and `column_info()` methods. **But where do they get their information from?** If they just query `*_tab_columns` as well, they're not of use to me.

I can't simply test because I didn't manage to pass the right parameters yet. The [Dbi Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.633/DBI.pm#table_info) says it is according to the database driver. The [Oracle DBD Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#table_info()) wasn't very helpfull to me as well, trial and error so far resulted in getting all objects or nothing at all.

At the moment I'm thinking of executing `describe` via `sqlplus` through a perl system call and parsing the output....but there *has* to be a better way.

**EDIT:**

The view `user_tab_columns`works as expected, if checking the right columns (see comments below ).

Comment: I think you misunderstood something from the documentation! user_columns is a table, which is always 100% up-to-date - the only thing changing with ANALYZE are the columns which include statistical data. But Columns like Name, Type... are always exactly like DESCRIBE

Comment: Hm that's what i thought as well, but: `select column_name, data_type, data_length from user_tab_columns where  table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_name = 'MY_COLUMN';` gives me a data length of 200. SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE')FROM dual;` shows 50 for the particular column, `DESCRIBE MY_TABLE` shows 50 as well. Executed in the same session/db-client-window of course. Allready thought about misinterpreting the data length value concering bytes and char for a varchar column, but for all other columns it fits.

Comment: If it is a VARCHAR Table, you have to look for the COLUMN: CHAR_LENGTH, because LENGTH is the reserved length in byte, which is 4 times the char length for UTF-8

Comment: The length depends on your encoding and if you created the Table with Length (XX BYTE) or (XX CHAR) if you use BYTE, the values will be the same, if you use CHAR, the length will be 4xchar_length. So you can have one table where it is the same for some columns and different for others

Comment: D'oh! That's it. Feeling a little stupid as I thought I had checked _all_ the other columns of `user_tab_columns` but obviously I didn't....at least the view works as I always expected. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have not found the DBD::Oracle documentation particularly helpful, but did you consider using the source code?

Here is the source for [table_info()](https://metacpan.org/source/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#L414) and [column_info()](https://metacpan.org/source/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#L414). Both subroutines largely seem to be spent building up SQL statements.

Comment: Ah thank you! So `column_info` indeed queries `all_tab_columns` and I don't need to worry anymore calling it...hopefully next time I think of the source-links myself :)